# Output a list of integer values at the same time by using a pointer dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In C++, following the code below:

```
    char *p = new char();
    *p = 'a';
    *(p+1)= 'b';
    *(p+2) ='\0';
    cout<<p<<endl;
```

we can get the output result: ab

When I want to write the code like this:

```
    int *p = new int();
    *p = 1;
    *(p+1)= 2;
    cout<<p<<endl;
```

It gives the result, but not 12 or something start with 12

Question is why the result goes wrong when changing it from char to integer? How to realize the goal that output a list of value by using a pointer dynamic array?

Comment: undefined behavior is obvious (and can result in time travel)

Comment: @quantdev You are right, but how can I output all the effective integer values in the array without using loop?

Comment: @JoeWang - that's a different question altogether. But start by looking at Barry's answer regarding how to safely allocate an int array (and if you know the size ahead of time, stay the heck away from `new int[3]` in the first place ... just use `int intsToOutput[3];`).

Comment: @JohnCastleman Thanks. I have knew that using int *p = new int() is not a safe way to allocate space. But what if I don't know how much space I need to allocate?

Comment: @JoeWang Then use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @cdhowie That hits my point. I am actually preparing a interview and they don't let me to use STL... Very painful to deal with the array initialization question without knowing the size.

Comment: @JoeWang If they don't let you use the standard library in an interview then *you don't want to work for them.* I will bet you money that their codebase is riddled with C++ anti-patterns based on the "I'm smarter than the standard library" mindset. **Stay the hell away.**  Effectively using the C++ standard library is a good 70-90% of modern C++ development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `char *` is a bit of a special case.

In the C days, `char *` was the only type we really had to deal with strings.  C++ makes it easier to interoperate with legacy code by providing streaming operators that treat `char *` values specially, by streaming out each character until a null character (`'\0'`) is encountered.

When you stream out `p` when it's an `int *` there is no special case -- you just get the raw pointer value displayed.

If you want a one-liner to display the elements in a standard container, you can combine `std::copy()` with `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(std::begin(some_array),
          std::end(some_array),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```

Since your array is allocated on the heap and stored in a pointer, `std::begin()` and `std::end()` won't work for you; you'll have to provide the end iterator manually:

```
std::copy(p, p + 2, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```

([See a demo](http://ideone.com/t0ulE5).)

---

But note that both code samples in your question are undefined behavior, because you allocate a *single* object of type `char` or `int` and then try to assign *beyond* it.  You write into memory you haven't allocated.  **Don't do this.**

To fix your cases, you need to allocate enough room for the objects you intend to store:

```
// Case one
char *p = new char[3];

// Case two
int *p = new int[2];
```

And, of course, don't forget to `delete[] p` in both cases -- or you could just use `std::string` in the first case and `std::vector<int>` in the second.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all, this is unsafe:

```
*(p+1)= 'b';
```

You only allocated one byte and now you're stomping on memory you don't own - which is undefined behavior. If you want to allocate 3 bytes, do it:

```
char* p = new char[3];
```

Secondly, this:

```
int* pi = new int;
cout << pi << endl;
```

Will print the address of the pointer. `char*` is special in that `cout` will actually print the C-style string that is pointed to, but for other types - you just get the address.

If you want to print 12, you have to dereference the pointer:

```
int* pi = new int(12);
cout << *pi << endl;
```

If you want to output 1 and 2, separately, you need an array:

```
int* pi = new int[2];
pi[0] = 1;
pi[1] = 2;
cout << pi[0] << ", " << pi[1] << endl;
```

Note that, again, `*(p + 1) = 2` in your code is stomping on memory you don't own.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I assign 50 values to the integer array and want to output all of them, I have no choice but using a loop?

Comment: @JoeWang No, you can use `std::copy()` as per my answer.